# NPM start failing

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-modules, npm-install, npm-start

I'm trying to run my back-end code on the local host. It was functioning perfectly until I added a video into the folder and ran a python program which used the video to output results which should be displayed on the localhost.

Before I ran the python program I installed opencv, python 3 and pip3.

All my other team members have the exact same structure and code and it is working perfectly for them.

After all this, I'm getting is this error:

> ```
> C:\Third_Year\IBM_project\ibm\back_end>npm start
>
> back-end@0.0.0 start C:\Third_Year\IBM_project\ibm\back_end
> node ./bin/www
>
> undefined:1
> [{'frame_number': 1, 'roi0': [101.78202823559488, 99.39509279584912, 49.546951219239915, 29.728170731543948], 'intensity0': 80.0, 'roi1': [101.78202823559488, 99.39509279584912, 49.546951219239915, 29.728170731543948], 'intensity1': 157.0},
>   ^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 2
>     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
>     at C:\Third_Year\IBM_project\ibm\back_end\routes\IntensityAPI.js:31:19
>     at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:63:3)
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! back-end@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the back-end@0.0.0 start script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\holly\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-16T11_03_34_055Z-debug.log
>
> C:\Third_Year\IBM_project\ibm\back_end>
> ```

I've tried

1. Running; `npm cache clean --force`
2. Deleting `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file by running:

   ```
   rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
   ```

   Or deleting it manually by going into the directory and right-click > delete / move to trash.
3. Running; `npm install` then to start again run; `npm start`

However this did not fix my problem, any other suggestions?

Comment: is that resolved? if it haven't, I can give you some idea may solve this problem

Comment: @VanTho this problem is solved thank u!